# Jquery or AJAX plugin for sorting

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins

Is there any jquery or AJAX plugin which will help in sorting?

I mean that I will be having a `div` with all alpha-numeric buttons on top, the `div` will be empty on page load, when someone clicks on any number pr alphabet letters, then it will display all the names starting with that letter or number. The names will be called from database.

If I clicked on A, then it will display me all the names starting with letter A.

Is there any plugin? or example related to the above thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call ajax every time user clicks letter. Example

-- js

```
$(".letter").bind('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
         url:'newContent.php?letter='+$(this).html(), 
         success:function(data){
             $("#content").html(data);
         }
    });
});
```

-- html

```
<span class="letter">a</span>
<span class="letter">b</span>
<span class="letter">c</span>
<span class="letter">d</span>
.
.
.
```

-php (newContent.php)

```
<?php
retreive_new_letter_data($_GET['letter']);
```

Comment: hey this will help me, is there any live example for this? So I can see the demo
Thanks for your help